# Rails first_or_create! creating null values in database table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using first_or_create to populate a table with a list of email subscribers (called members).  The code is as follows:

```
    def community_members=(members)
        self.members = members.split(",").map do |member|   
            Member.where(email: member.strip, community_id: self.id).first_or_create! unless member.strip == nil
        end
    end
```

Everything works fine, except that when I add additional emails to the same community, the table turns the "community_id" column for all previous rows to NULL.

Here's the server log:

```
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."email" = $1 AND "members"."community_id" = $2  ORDER BY "members"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "lisa@holy.com"], ["community_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "members" ("email", "community_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "lisa@holy.com"], ["community_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-04-30 16:14:25.930012"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-30 16:14:25.930012"]]

  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."community_id" = $1  [["community_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "members" SET "community_id" = NULL WHERE "members"."community_id" = $1 AND "members"."id" = 30  [["community_id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

The first "Member" load does exactly what it's supposed to do.  But for some reason it always ends with the second Member load that goes in and sets all "community_id" fields to NULL.

Right now I call :community_member from a form on a community page:

```
    <%= form_for(@community) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :community_members, class:"form-control input-lg", placeholder:"Please add your list of comma separated member email addresses here" %>
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-lg btn-green btn-block pad-top" %>
    <% end %>
```

Seems like I'm missing something obvious here.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: can you remove the ! from first_or_create!, also I guess community_members function is in Community model. Could you be creating this in a model before the community object is saved.

Comment: I tried removing the ! and it didn't make a difference.  The community object already exists before any members are added, so I don't think it needs to be saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to find by the unique attribute, email, and create by community name, I think.

If that's the case, you'll have to do something like:

```
Member.where(email: member.strip).first_or_create(community: self) unless...
```

If you have records with non-unique emails, you'll have to redesign your associations.

```
class Subscriber
    #this should have the email attribute
    has_many :community_subscribers
    has_many :communities, through: :community_subscribers
end

class CommunitySubscriber
    #this is a 'bridge' table
    belongs_to :subscriber
    belongs_to :community
end

class Community
    has_many :community_subscribers
    has_may :subscribers, through: :community_subscribers

    #I suggest new method and arg names
    #Using self will keep the query within the scope of the community you are working on
    #This also allows for creation of Subscriber records if you insist placing that here
    #are you sure you want to map instead of just iterating the split list of emails?
    def new_subscribers(emails)
    emails.split(",").map do |email|
        clean_email = email.strip
        subscriber = Subscriber.where(email: clean_email).find_or_create unless clean_email.blank?   
        self.community_subscribers.where(subscriber: subscriber).first_or_create unless subscriber.blank?
    end
end
end
```

Docs:
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create

Comment: Yes, I need it to be unique to community.  So I could have the same email address, but one with community_id = 1 and another with community_id = 2.  Any thoughts on how I can make this work?

Comment: Ok, let's think about options with 'helper' tables.  Can we do something like create a `member_community` table?  Then we create unique 'helper' records that you can rely on for these associations.  I can write that up if you need help.

Comment: can you explain in more detail?  i have a members table with columns email and community_id.  i'm pretty new to rails and working with databases, so any detail would help a lot.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going with this.  I use a similar join table set up in a different part of my app.  But how do I then update the record to add new emails and ensure uniqueness within communities but not across the app?  I've updated the question so you can see how I call the community_member method.  Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: Joe - yes!  that worked like a charm.  thank you.  can you explain to me the difference between using map and just iterating through the list of split emails?

Comment: @Lorenz, glad I could help!  It would be easiest for you to understand `.map` by reading this: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map.

Comment: Joe - I seem to be having a problem with the set up you suggested now.  Not sure why this started happening all of a sudden, but now I get "undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass"  on this line: self.community_subscribers.where(subscriber: subscriber).first_or_create unless subscriber.blank?.  do you know what's going on?

Comment: I've got community_subscribers set up as "has_many :community_subscribers, dependent: :delete_all"

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out.  the :community_subscribers apparently had a conflict with the method name in the model which was named the same thing.  when I changed the method name to new_community_subscribers it started working again.